# Finding the area

Tags: calculus, area

A point P moves inside the triangle formed by $$A (0,0) , B(1,√3), C(2,0) $$such that min{ PA,PB,PC} =1 then the area bounded by the curve traced by P is
$$a. 3√3+3\pi/2$$

$$b. 3√3-3\pi/2$$

$$c. √3-\pi/2$$

$$d. √3+\pi/2 $$

I dont understand the meaning of min{ PA,PB,PC} =1. What would the graph look like. im completely clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Taking the diagram from here](http://new.openstudy.com/updates/524713f9e4b034054f3ddcb8)**:

---

Those circular rings are each of radius $1$. It is also easy to see that the triangle $ABC$ is equilateral with side length of $2$. The path traces by the point $P$ is thus given by $${Ar_{req}} = {Ar_{\triangle ABC}} -3{Ar_{Sec}}$$ We can find the area of the sector as $$Ar_{Sec} = \frac{\pi(1)^2}{6} =\frac{\pi}{6}$$ Also, $Ar_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} (2)^2 = \sqrt{3}$. Thus, $$Ar_{req} = \sqrt{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: $ABC$ isn't  equilateral.

Comment: @Theorem The vertex B is actually $(1,\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: This is what I thought (and answered) aswell. However, the OP seems to disagree. EDIT: Up until now because you edited his post.

Comment: well b should be (1,√3) because the answer that you are getting is correct

Comment: @Tetrahydrocannabinol That's why I also edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$P$ "travels" on the red curve. Because only on these arcs the distance from $P$ to one of the vertices is $1$. The area enclosed inside isn't hard to find by substracting areas.

EDIT: I just realized $y_B=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. Did you mean $y_B=\sqrt 3$? Because otherwize there's no enclosed area!